# Acquire token silently using ADAL JS

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have already established session with Azure AD through Open ID Connect, how do I acquire token silently from the browser, I mean without browser redirect, is it possible using ADAL JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible. If you are using Angular, all you need to do is specifying the resource you want to target at init time, in the endpoints structure - see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/.
If you aren't using Angular, you can use the lower level functions available in adal.js. In particular, see AuthenticationContext.prototype.acquireToken in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/adal.js